# Объясните фрагмент кода Java SE

Tags: java

```
void removeSummerDates(Map<String, Date> map) {
    map.entrySet().removeIf(pair -> pair.getValue().getMonth() > 4 & pair.getValue().getMonth() < 8);
}
```

Это фрагмент кода — решение задачки по удалению летних дат из списка. Я не понимаю что за переменная **pair**, если это вообще переменная (в коде нигде нет её объявления). Объясните новичку в программировании что она такое или подскажите ресурс где можно прочитать про неё. Спасибо.

Comment: прочитай про лямбда выражения

Comment: Это аргумент предиката, содержащий текущий элемент коллекции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeIf` это метод который принимает тип `Predicate` (тип появился в Java 8). `Predicate` - это функциональный интерфейс который имеет всего один метод `test` который возвращает истинна или лож, поэтому в тело метода `removeIf` может быть передано лямбда выражение для которого "будет вызван метод тест предиката позже".

`pair` - это переменная лямбда выражения которая в твоём случае имеет тип `Map.Entry<String, Date>`.

Рекомендую прочитать книгу по лямбда выражениям, это тебе очень поможет [Лямбда выражения в Java 8](https://www.livelib.ru/book/1001452255/about-lyambdavyrazheniya-v-java-8-funktsionalnoe-programmirovanie-richard-uorberton)